# Unable to set the ID of an instance

Tags: codefluent

What is unique about my situation is that the ID's can not be randomly assigned so I set it's value within the instance. I created several instances of an entity using the modeler. Below is the XML created:

```
  <cf:entity name="Test4" namespace="Amikids.TimeTracking" categoryPath="/Amikids.TimeTracking">
    <cf:property name="Id" key="true" typeName="int" />
    <cf:property name="Name" />
    <cf:instance>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Id">10</cf:instanceValue>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Name">Test 1</cf:instanceValue>
    </cf:instance>
    <cf:instance>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Id">20</cf:instanceValue>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Name">Test 2</cf:instanceValue>
    </cf:instance>
    <cf:instance>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Id">30</cf:instanceValue>
      <cf:instanceValue name="Name">Test 3</cf:instanceValue>
    </cf:instance>
  </cf:entity>
```

There are 2 things that are not working as expected:

1. The records inserted do not use the ID specificed in the model/xml. Instead they were created incrementally starting at 1:

(The below is displayed in a code snippet only to prevent StackOverflow from reformatting my list so all records appear on one line)

```html
ID Name
1  Test 1
2  Test 2
3  Test 3
```

2. When I build the model a second time duplicate records are inserted.

(The below is displayed in a code snippet only to prevent StackOverflow from reformatting my list so all records appear on one line)

```html
    ID Name
    1  Test 1
    2  Test 2
    3  Test 3
    4  Test 1
    5  Test 2
    6  Test 3
```

Comment: The Id property is translated to an identity column in the database. Thus, you cannot set the value of the Id column explicitly. To be able to set the value of the Id column you must set `persistenceIdentity="false"` in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Although specifying the ID in the instance does not appear to be work, as a simple work around I created the records using code, which allowed me to specify the ID. This has been verified with the following code snippet.

```
         Amikids.TimeTracking.Test4 test4  = new Amikids.TimeTracking.Test4();
         test4.Id = 100;
         test4.Name = "Test 100";
         test4.Save();

         test4 = new Amikids.TimeTracking.Test4();
         test4.Id = 200;
         test4.Name = "Test 200";
         test4.Save();
```